# how to let a login button become a drop down menu after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

I am making a social website and encounter some problems about Facebook login.

I can login successfully.
The problem is that I hope after the user click the login button on navigation bar, the button will become a drop down menu.

If the user click the drop down menu, they can go to their profile site or logout.

[Sorry for my English presentation so I draw picture to make you understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN7k4.jpg)

```
<a id="login_button">Login</a>
```

and below is part of my js code.

```
  $(function(){

     $("#login_button").click(function() {
       FB.login();
       get_my_profile();
     });

  });

  var get_my_profile =function() {

     FB.api("/me", function(response){
        var username =response.name;
        $("#profile_name").html(username);
     });

     FB.api("/me/picture", function(response) {
        var userpicture =response.data.url; 
        $("#profile_picture").attr("src", userpicture);
     });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FB.getLoginStatus() to determine if user is logged in or not.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your app

  $("#userMenu").show();


  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app

    $("#login_button").show();

  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
  }
 });



<a id="login_button" style="display: none;">Login</a>


<div class="btn-group" id="userMenu" style="display: none;">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    UserName <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a id="userProfile" href="#">User Profile</a></li>
    <li><a id="logOut" href="#">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It really help me a lot because I never think of using  Jquery's show() function and Css to determine my login status.But I didn't use style="hidden", I use display:none in Css file. I am so grateful for your help!

Comment: You are Welcome! That was my mistake, sorry for that. I meant `"style=display: none;"`